# Calculate the percentage and put it into a progressbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have some data from the World Cup 2014, where I store if the person has bet correctly on matches.

It looks like this (data in a angularjs-controller):

```
 $scope.users=  [{
             id: 1,
             name: 'Jake',
             loss: 22,        
             win: 10
         },
         {
             id: 2,
             name: 'Bran',
             loss: 18,
             win: 14
         }];
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of how many wins there have been.
That could be done if I divide total wins by the total matches, 18/(18+14) = 56% for example.
I need get data from each user in the json and calculate the percentage of wins. 
I would later like to add that percentage to a progressbar for each user in the view:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
    <span class="sr-only">40% Wins</span>
  </div>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped" ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{(user.win)/(user.win+user.loss)}}%">
    <span class="sr-only">{{(user.win)/(user.win+user.loss)}}% Wins</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough, i need % for each users, and present it on each users progress bar.

Comment: I don't understand that. Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Ok so each users has data of "Wins" let's just say i would like to present that "Win" for each user in their own progressbar. Jake has one progressbar and Bran has one progressbar, i need to fetch the "Win" from each user and put it in the corresponding progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly for you.

```
const users = [ // Total number of each user trials = 32
  { id: 1, name: 'Jake', win: 10, loss: 22 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ann', win: 14, loss: 18 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Emeka', win: 30, loss: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mike', win: 32, loss: 0 },
];

const calculateWinPercentage = (win, loss) => {
  // add each user win and loss,
  // divide it by user win,
  // multiply the result by 100.

  console.log((win / (win + loss)) * 100);
  return (win / (win + loss)) * 100;
};    

<div class="info_div">
  {users.map((user) => {
    const winPercentage = calculateWinPercentage(user.win, user.loss);

    return (
      <div key={user.id} class="progress">
        <div
          class="progress-bar"
          role="progressbar"
          style={{
            width: winPercentage + "%",
          }}
          aria-valuenow={winPercentage}
          aria-valuemin="0"
          aria-valuemax="100"
        >
          {winPercentage}% Wins
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: please add comment to your code and explain your answer